# Java: String Manipulation without Spaces

Tags: java, string, split

So given data for example:

```
a898            //result string1=a  string2=898
b832            //string1=b string2=832
c3232           //string1=c string2=3232
d938202         //string1=d string2=938202
```

I'm attempting to get the letter and put it in a `String`, and then have the rest of the numbers in another `String`. I am using `charAt(0)` to get the letter, but am having issues finding a way to split the numbers given that they aren't all of the same length.

One way I used, when there weren't 26 diff options, in another program was replacing `a` with `a|`, `b` with `b|`, and so on and then splitting on the `|`. It led to very ugly code and I was hoping for another option. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use like

```
    String str = "d938202";
    String string1 = str.substring(0, 1);
    String string2 = str.substring(1);
```

Comment: `str.substring(1, str.length());` should give you same results as `str.substring(1);` if I remember correctly.

Comment: awww beautiful. Thank you @Ashiquizzaman, I truly appreciate it

Comment: @Pshemo, Yes both gives same results. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use something like:

```
String[] arr = "d938202".split("(?<=[a-z])");
//arr[0] = "d"
//arr[1] = "938202"
```

`split` uses regular expression (Regex) syntax which allows us to describe place to split on. In this case thanks to [look-around mechanisms](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) we can describe this place as one which have alphabetic character (a-z) before it.